# How to add space between backgroundimages and elements in css?

Tags: css

I was trying to make uber's site.I want to add space between background image and div.

I tried using margin , padding and top 50% but none of them worked.I just want to add space from top

Html

```
<header id="main-image">
    <div class="main-navigation">

    </div>
</header>
```

Css

```
#main-image {
    background: url(/images/earn_2x.webp);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -55;
}

.main-navigation {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 200px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Please explain in detail and add full code

Answer (score 1):

Try `background-position`. This works only when background image is not set in repeat mode.

For eg:

```
background-position-y: 10px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

This will add 10px space from top.